# Could not run jasmine test case in docker container in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, google-chrome-headless

I have been trying to run `jasmine` test for my UI code written in `Angular 7` in a docker container which is build on `node:10-alpine`. I have tried to run installing chromium and puppeteer but I chrome headless seems not have been captured. I am getting below error:

> WARN [launcher]: ChromeHeadless have not captured in 210000 ms, killing.

> WARN [launcher]: ChromeHeadless was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL.
> WARN [launcher]: ChromeHeadless was not killed by SIGKILL in 2000 ms, > continuing.
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1

I have tried below heck also:

- increasing captureTimeout and browserNoActivityTimeout
- added few more flags other than '--no-sandbox' as below

```
customLaunchers: 

{
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox:{
        base: "ChromeHeadless",
        flags: [
          "--no-sandbox",
          "--no-proxy-server",
          "--disable-web-security",
          "--disable-gpu",
          "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
          '--no-proxy-server',
          '--proxy-bypass-list=*',
          '--window-size=1920,1080',
          '--remote-debugging-port=9222'
        ]
      }
    }
```

I have also added

```
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();
```

in karma config

But no luck at all. Could anyone please provide me best resolution? Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling almost a week, I somehow figured out the fix. With minimal configuration in my customLaunchers with just `"--no-sandbox"` flag and without puppeteer, I was able to run my jasmine test case in the docker container by setting below environment variables properly:

```
CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser and CHROME_PATH=/usr/lib/chromium/
```

Below is the command I run in my terminal to check if test are executing successfully:

```
docker run -e CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser -e CHROME_PATH=/usr/lib/chromium/ -v path-to-project:/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app dockerImage sh -c "apk add chromium && npm install && npm rebuild node-sass && npm run test:ci"
```

In my jenkins file I have added below lines to run the test cases in the Jenkins pipeline:

```
withEnv(["CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser", "CHROME_PATH=/usr/lib/chromium/"]) {
   sh 'apk add chromium && npm install && npm run test:ci && npm run build'
}
```